# $q.reject not working and going back to error block in Angular

Tags: angularjs, promise

Inside an HTTP call, I am checking for the response

```
   promise.then(function(res){
        var value = null;
        var keepGoing = true;
        for(var key in res) {
            if(keepGoing){
                //If the response object has a null value for any of the given keys, we assume the API has failed
                if(value === null)
                    keepGoing = false;
            }
        }
        //And we reject the promise
        if(!keepGoing){
            $q.reject("Bad data");
        }

        //Else, we loop through the keys
        if(res.length != 0){
            var keysArray = Object.keys(res);   
            ....
            ....

    },function(error){
        vm.continuing = false;
        vm.errorInContinue = true;
    });
```

**What I want that whenever I reject that promise, do not execute the next lines and jump to the error block.**

What am I doing wrong?

I tried `return $q.reject("Some bad data")` also, but did not help.

Comment: `return $q.reject("Bad data");` is correct way. But as you're expecting to call current error block, the subsequent `chain promise` function will get called by this way.

Comment: @PankajParkar I tried but this is not going to `fucntion(error) ...` block.

Comment: Apart from having to use `return`, have a look at the [difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)